# all the commands are not getting executed in bat file?

Tags: batch-file

after the `startup.bat` command I wanted to start chrome with url: `http://localhost:8080/Nexus` but bat file getting stopped after tomcat is being started up.

Code in the batch file is as follows:

```
@echo off
start cmd
cd I:\Users\5251966\Nexus
echo yes|copy catalina.bat I:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\bin
echo yes|copy tomcat-users.xml I:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\conf
cd I:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\bin
startup.bat
start chrome http://localhost:8080/Nexus
```

Comment: please give solution.......anyone........if you are able to get ans

Comment: Try `Call startup.bat` and you're probably best advised to use `CD /D` too.

Comment: thanks a lot.....................very good solution its working

Comment: sai bhargav, if an answer has provided a solution to your issue, please consider marking it as accepted; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "srcDir=I:\Users\5251966\Nexus"
Set "dstDir=I:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.55"
Copy /Y "%srcDir%\catalina.bat" "%dstDir%\bin"
Copy /Y "%srcDir%\tomcat-users.xml" "%dstDir%\conf"
CD /D "%dstDir%\bin"
Call "startup.bat"
Start chrome http://localhost:8080/Nexus
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `call` to call other batch files from a batch file, otherwise your parent batch file terminates and won't run any more commands after invoking the child:

```
call startup.bat
```